# Can a judge remove the requirement of a jury?

Tags: united-kingdom, jury, judge

From the song *The Trial* by Pink Floyd

> The evidence before the court is incontrovertible
>
> There's no need for the jury to retire

I know I shouldn't read too much into a song (which takes place in the mind of the protagonist), and I also know that "showing feelings of an almost human nature" is not a real crime, but I'd like to know if it has a little basis in reality. Is it legal for a judge to simply decide on a verdict because s/he decides the evidence is so strong that the jury (who have already sat through the case) isn't required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

It's called a [directed verdict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdict#Directed_verdict) (or [judgment as a matter of law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_as_a_matter_of_law) in the USA).

When the judge reaches the conclusion that, on the evidence, no reasonable jury could find otherwise, the judge may rule what the verdict shall be.